# Display property of a div is not changing from "none" to "block" in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dojo

I have a popup which comes on click of a button. I am changing display property of the div from "none" to "block" by javascript on click of a button, that div is inside a popup. When I am checking display property of that div in console it shows me "block" only but actually that div is still not visible & display property value doesn't got changed in HTML of page.

**HTML code in jsp file**

I have a button in popup, on click event of that button below line of code is being called
**Change display property from "none" to "block"**

```
dojo.style(dojo.byId('error_text_reorder'), "display", "block");
```

When I click on button this code is being executed but div is still not visible.
But If I reload the popup than div is visible.

Apart from this dojo code I tried with this js code also

```
document.getElementsByName("error_text_qty")[1].style.display='block';
```

This works fine in firefox but doesn't work in IE.

Any cross browser solution for this Guys.....?

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Please make use of them in future. :-)

Comment: Post as minimal as possible code to replicate your issue in a fiddle!

Comment: Which version of dojo are you using? Please add some code so we can see what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Both dojo and jquery have this basic support changing style of dom elments cross browser. There could be a couple of solutions to this problem.

1. **Upgrade your version of dojo.** Each dojo release supports a certain set of browsers. The version of dojo you are using may not support IE browser version your using.
2. **Get by ID instead of name, or vise versa.** Your two code examples are using two different queries, the dojo code is grabbing the div by id `dojo.byId`, the JS example is by name `getElementsByName`. Do you really have an id set in one element and a name on the other in your div? Evaluate and adjust your code if needed.

Try posting more relevant code so we can better help you, such as the HTML of the dom element you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: Hi Danny, I am using dojo version 1.8.7.

Comment: I used this code to change display property value , it works fine in firefox but doesn't work in IE. Strange thing is when I checked value of display property in IE console it shows block only. But div is still not visible on pop up.                   document.getElementsByName("error_text_qty").[1].style.display='block';  document.getElementsByName("error_text_qty")[1].style.color='red'; Given id (error_text_qty) is an id of div element this div is also inside a div.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Can you post the HTML you are trying to manipulate, such as the div and maybe the popup as well? Thanks!

Comment: I am using IE 8 & IE 11. I am using dijit/Dialog (dojo) to create pop up. <h5><div style="display: none;" name="error_text_qty" class="error_text error_text_qty" id="error_text_reorder"> Some Text </div>
</h5> This <h5> tag is also under a div element. I changed display property by using :  document.getElementById("error_text_reorder").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("error_text_reorder").style.color="red"; But div is still not visible on popup, while this line "document.getElementById("error_text_reorder").style.display" shows "block" only in IE 8 Console.